# Как получить переменную экземпляра класса

Tags: java, ооп

Всем привет. У меня есть такой list  `List<Family> family = Arrays.asList(new Dad(), new Son(), new GrandPa());`

дальше в нем я рандомно выбираю экземпляр класса

```
  family.get( ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(family.size())
).eat(chees);
```

и ем сыр.Это класс Человек с методом для еды.

```
 void eat(Chees chees) {
        int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101);
        chees.eat(a);
        System.out.println( " съел " + a + " грамм");
    }
```

У  отца сына и деда есть приватная переменная name

вопрос в том, как мне в методе eat вывести эту переменную, чтобы в итоге получилось

Отец съел .. грамм
Сын съел .. грамм
Дед съел .. грамм

Comment: `System.out.println(this.name +  " съел " + a + " грамм");`

Comment: В [ответе на прошлый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343256/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0) уже было указано нечто похожее.  Метод `eat` класса `Family` имеет доступ к полю `name` того же класса.

Comment: В прошлом вопросе не были сделаны перменные в классах mom dad и kid. Сейчас я их добавил, и надо сделать так, чтобы именно эти переменные выводились, в этом и загвоздка) через this.name не сделать так просто)

Comment: Плюс я немного изменил ваш вариант решения задачи. Вместо интерфейса теперь обычный класс Family с методом еды. Остальные классы просто от него наследнуются

Comment: Дело в том что у вас приватная переменая для получения доступа к ней нужен Геттер

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у всех классов-потомков `Family` имеется общее свойство/поле `name`, вероятно, имеет смысл перенести его на уровень этого родительского класса `Family`, и тогда метод `Family::eat` будет иметь доступ к данному полю.

```java
public class Family {
    private String name; // или protected String name

    void eat(Chees chees) {
        int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101);
        chees.eat(a);
        System.out.println(this.name + " съел " + a + " грамм");
    }
}
```

Относительное преимущество такого способа в том, что он позволяет избежать дублирования кода в классах-потомках, однако обратная сторона этого - высокая связанность (high coupling) потомков с родителем, так как достаточно проблематично будет изменить способ печати для каждого из потомков.

---

Другой способ: сделать класс `Family` абстрактным, задав в нём некий абстрактный метод -- либо getter `getName`, либо целый метод для печати сообщения о поедании сыра, реализовать эти методы в классах-потомках, и вызвать их из метода `Family::eat`:

- `abstract String getName()`

```java
public abstract class Family {
    public abstract String getName();

    void eat(Chees chees) {
        int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101);
        chees.eat(a);
        System.out.println(getName() + " съел " + a + " грамм");
    }
}
```

```java
class Dad extends Family {
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

- `abstract void cheeseEaten(int cheese);` - выводит всё сообщение

```java
public abstract class Family {
    public abstract void cheeseEaten(int cheese);

    void eat(Chees chees) {
        int a = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 101);
        chees.eat(a);
        cheeseEaten(a);
    }
}
```

```java
class Dad extends Family {
    @Override
    public void cheeseEaten(int cheese) {
        System.out.println("Папаша съел " + cheese + " г сыра");
    }
}
```

В данном случае связанность между классами уменьшается, и каждый класс-потомок может реализовать обработку информации о съеденном сыре по-своему.